# Transistor functionality in a given schematic

Tags: power-supply, power, transistors, pnp

Can anyone tell me what is the functionality of the transistor in this schematic ?

[image]

Comment: Can you figure out what the current through L1 is?

Comment: What do you mean by L1 ? For 78L15 is 1.5A

Answer (score 2):

It lights the LED to show that *both* outputs are on and above around 8V or so.

Note that the base is at the *common* terminal - I will call this zero for now.

When the positive output exceeds about 5.6V, ZD1 (a [zener diode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zener_diode)) breaks over and conducts. If the positive output were at 15V, then there will be about 5mA of current in the emitter. (15V - 5.6V - 0.6V) / 1.8k

The LED cannot light up unless there is a negative voltage output though as there is no bias for the LED.

Once the negative output exceeds 5.6V (for ZD2) plus the LED minimum forward voltage, there is a current path and the LED lights.

Answer (score 1):

The transistor circuit causes the LED to light only if both power rails are working.

Comment: It's not a great quality answer, but if JP1 is connected and 78L15 and 79L15 are power, then the LED will light.